# Is there a difference between activations functions in tensorflow? tf.nn.tanh vs tf.tanh

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to setup a neuronal network and I am asking myself if there is a difference between those two functions?

tf.nn.tanh vs tf.tanh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no difference.

In the `tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py` file (that's where `tf.nn` is defined) we can find the definition of `tanh`:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops import tanh
```

also, there's this `TODO` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0b723590631432584d0761c03285eabb55116c6d/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py)

```
# TODO(cwhipkey): sigmoid and tanh should not be exposed from tf.nn.
```

Thus, probably tanh will be removed from the `tf.nn` package.

Hence `tf.tanh` (that's defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf18c6d384a96a53b448bd51a90c117af0ed7c96/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py)) is the one to use.

Answer (score 5):

Easy enough to confirm they are the same:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: tf.nn.tanh
Out[2]: <function tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops.tanh>

In [3]: tf.tanh
Out[3]: <function tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops.tanh>

In [4]: tf.nn.tanh == tf.tanh
Out[4]: True

In [5]: tf.__version__
Out[5]: '0.11.0rc1'
```

Answer (score 2):

They are the exact same alias to `tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops.tanh`.

Same thing goes for `tf.sigmoid` and `tf.nn.sigmoid`.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't any difference.

The availability of both is probably due to the library evolving and still changing its API, being still in an initial state of maturing.
We could expect the library to avoid those fundamental duplications in the future when the main API is finally set (I'd expect so towards 2.0).